# Registration success process coding/UX question

Tags: registration

I have a question:

I run a website community where user have to register, verify their email, complete a wizard with their data and then upload a photo.

i noticed so far on 500 new registrations (email and pass sent to my db), 100 didn't verified their email, 100 they partially complete their profile, 100 didn't upload a photo.

my doubt is if this is a natural number of "dead" users or if is due to my code, maybe some bugs in the process that don't allow to do all the actions properly...so far no one sent an email complaining about bugs so i have no idea where to start fine-tuning my code..

let em say i tried my code in any browser PC and mac and it seems to work, but users have unexpected behaviors sometimes...

there is any script or best practice to analyze this steps and code?
thanks

Comment: user's change their mind while while registration, that what is do, I think it best to understand the user's mind and and make interface to attract them (but perfection is nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recreating any possible user created errors for example not completing all fields or mispelling a vital field.

Also forcing users to verify with emails and to complete a wizard may deter users from using the website. There are those users which are just impatient.

Again, just test for all possible scenarios where a user could make an error and fix them accordingly, the data doesn't look like its an indication the there is a major bug in your code but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

If your process is too complicated or even too long, users will lose interest and do either stop or do that later.

If you have image restrictions, note that the users do not have images at hand to match your requirements.
Some do not even want to upload an image.

Some People just want to take a quick look at the site so they don't bother to complete the wizard.

Try to give users a peek if email is to be verified. I won't bother verifying my email if I don't know what I will benefit from it.

Believe me. Took me months to complete my Facebook profile. Your site won't be any different.